# In nextTick component is not redrawn

Tags: animation, vuejs2

Please, look at my code, I assign a new value to the variable in data and var width have value 100. After that, when animation end, i try return value to var width 100, and start animation again, but Vue does not assign new value 100 and stay 0. But if i will do this with setTimeout it's work perfect. Why is this not happening in nextTick?

link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pucjLmtv/)

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
        width: 100,
    time: 0
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.time = 5000;
        this.width = 0;

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.rerenderBar();
      }, 5100)

    }, 1000)

  },
  methods: {
      rerenderBar() {
        this.time = 0;
        this.width = 100;

      /* this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.time = 5000;
              this.width = 0;
      }) */

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.time = 5000;
        this.width = 0;
      }, 1500)
    }
  }
})


<div id="app">
      <div class="progress-bar-wrap">
        <div class="progress-bar" :style="{
              'width': width + '%',
              'transition-duration': `${time}ms`
            }"></div>    
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that because `$nextTick` runs after `Vue's DOM update cycle` and your animations are powered by css transitions directly on the element (not handled by Vue), the `$nextTick` happens immediately after calling `renderBar` **It does not wait for your animation to complete**.

If you need to wait for the animation to finish, you can look into using [Vue Transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Overview) and use [Javascript Hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks) to reset the width of the bar when the animation finishes.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i solved the problem using reflow. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fh7yws5v/)